# Problem displaying data Reactjs Expressjs

Tags: reactjs, json, express, axios

I get response from axios, when i do "dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name" the page becomes blank, if i copy the axios response to file, import it and use "Record.Roles[0].name" it works, what im doing wrong?

```
import Record from './asd.json';

      this.state = {
      dataUtilizador:[],
      content: ""
    };
      
      getUser(id) {
        UserService.findUser(id)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({
             dataUtilizador: response.data,
            });
           // console.log(response.data)
          })
          .catch(e => {
           alert(e)
          });
      }

    const {dataUtilizador} = this.state;   
        return( 
      <div className="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label>Roles</label>
      <select class="custom-select" onChange={this.onChangeEstado} required>
    
        <option selected value="test"> { Record.Roles[0].name }</option>
        <option selected value="test"> { dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name }</option> 
    </select>
             )
```

**Responde from axios**

```
  {
        "IDUtilizador": 7,
        "username": "utilizador4",
        "email": "denisevink@mphaotu.com",
        "nome": "Júlio César Luís",
        "estado": true,
        "contacto": "645564906",
        "morada": "R Sarmento Pimentel 93 2830-048 BARREIRO",
        "datacriacao": "2022-07-17T22:12:55.544Z",
        "imagem": null,
        "primeirologin": true,
        "Roles": [
           {
              "IDRole": 1,
              "name": "user"
           }
        ]
     }
```

**Error when i get the blank page**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: Your initial state of `dataUtilizador` is an empty array, so the first render will have a problem accessing `dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name` -- `Roles` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer console when the page turns blank. What error message is being logged? Please add this info to your post.
Otherwise, it might be because `dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name` is not defined at first. Try the following:

Change:

```
<option selected value="test"> { dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name }</option>
```

To:

```
{ dataUtilizador && <option selected value="test"> { dataUtilizador.Roles[0].name }</option> }
```

Comment: still does not work, already put the error in the post!